# Using MEDIAN with GROUP BY

Tags: mariadb, median

As of MariaDB 10.3.3 there exist `MEDIAN` function.
Unfortunately there is a little problem when I try to use it with `GROUP BY` statement (currently using v10.3.9).

Given following table:

```
CREATE TABLE testmed
  (
     id       INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
          PRIMARY KEY(id),
     group_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
     score    INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  );
```

Filling it up with some data:

```
INSERT INTO testmed (group_id, score) 
VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,2), (1,2), (1,3), (2,5), (2,7), (2,9), (2,11), (2,11);
```

Now I am getting different results with and without `GROUP BY` in query:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT group_id, score, MEDIAN(score) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) FROM testmed;
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
| group_id | score | MEDIAN(score) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) |
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
|        1 |     1 |                               2.0000000000 |
|        1 |     2 |                               2.0000000000 |
|        1 |     2 |                               2.0000000000 |
|        1 |     2 |                               2.0000000000 |
|        1 |     3 |                               2.0000000000 |
|        2 |     5 |                               9.0000000000 |
|        2 |     7 |                               9.0000000000 |
|        2 |     9 |                               9.0000000000 |
|        2 |    11 |                               9.0000000000 |
|        2 |    11 |                               9.0000000000 |
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT group_id, score, MEDIAN(score) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) FROM testmed GROUP BY group_id;
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
| group_id | score | MEDIAN(score) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) |
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
|        1 |     1 |                               1.0000000000 |
|        2 |     5 |                               5.0000000000 |
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
```

First one is correct, but why it is not working properly with `GROUP BY`.
Currently I am using query nesting like that:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM (SELECT group_id, score, MEDIAN(score) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) FROM testmed) t GROUP BY group_id;
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
| group_id | score | MEDIAN(score) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) |
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
|        1 |     1 |                               2.0000000000 |
|        2 |     5 |                               9.0000000000 |
+----------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

but it feels so wrong doing it that way.

What is right way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your second query is technically invalid:

```
SELECT
    group_id,
    score,
    MEDIAN(score) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id)
FROM testmed
GROUP BY group_id;
```

The reason it is invalid is because you are selecting `score` which does not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.  The issue here is *which* value of `score` do you intend the database to use for each `group_id`?  What appears to be happening here is that MariaDB is arbitrarily choosing the minimum value of `score`.  But since there is only a single `score` value, the median just returns that single value.

Keep in mind that analytic functions are evaluated *after* the `GROUP BY` aggregation takes place.  I think this is the query you were intending to run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    group_id,
    MEDIAN(score) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) score_median
FROM testmed;
```

If this doesn't work, because MariaDB doesn't like using `DISTINCT` with `MEDIAN`, then you can try subquerying:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    group_id,
    score_median
FROM
(
    SELECT
        group_id,
        MEDIAN(score) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id) score_median
    FROM testmed
) t;
```

Comment: What version of MariaDB you are using? Your query raises `You have an error in your SQL syntax;` error in mine (10.3.9). Unfortunately `MEDIAN` seems to be window only function (not aggregative) and that brought me here to ask question how other people handle it.

Comment: @DevilaN I have updated my answer with a query which might be along the lines of what you were really trying to do.  I did not know about `MEDIAN` being a window function only.

Comment: Your answer seems to be logically the same as my last example which I felt is a bit sneaky way to do this. Although thank you for your proposition.

Comment: @DevilaN - I succeeded with 10.3.21.  What was your exact statement and the full syntax error message?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - `GROUP BY` is distinctly faster than `DISTINCT`.  (At least in one test I ran.)

Comment: @RickJames: It was version 10.3.9. Unfortunately for this question, I have moved to v10.4.x and it no longer rises syntax error. Still, there is no good material about using MEDIAN, so this part of my original question is actual.